# B&R PLC. Calculate new offset after write or how to write data to new line

Tags: file-io, offset, plc, br-automation-studio

I have this program which creates file on USB stick. The problem is it is only saving one line (rewriting same line). I would need after each cycle it would write the data to new line . I think it has to do something with offset I need to calculate offset so it doesn't start from 0 every time. Here is the part of the code

```
10: DevLink_0.enable := TRUE;
    DevLink_0.pDevice := ADR('Disk');
    DevLink_0.pParam := ADR(cesta_k_USB);
    DevLink_0();

    IF DevLink_0.status =0 THEN
        step :=20;
    END_IF

20: FileCreate_0.enable := TRUE;
    FileCreate_0.pDevice := ADR('Disk');
    FileCreate_0.pFile := ADR('results.csv');
    FileCreate_0();

    IF FileCreate_0.status = 0 THEN
        identification_file := FileCreate_0.ident;
        offset :=0;
        step :=30;
    END_IF

    IF FileCreate_0.status = fiERR_EXIST THEN 
        step :=25;
    END_IF

25: FileOpen_0.enable := TRUE;
    FileOpen_0.pDevice :=  ADR('Disk');
    FileOpen_0.pFile := ADR('results.csv');
    FileOpen_0.mode := FILE_W;
    FileOpen_0();

    IF FileOpen_0.status = 0 THEN
        identification_file := FileOpen_0.ident;
        offset := FileOpen_0.filelen;
        step := 30;
    END_IF

30: data:=INT_TO_STRING(y);
    data:=INSERT(data,'$r$n',LEN(data));
    FileWrite_0.enable := TRUE;
    FileWrite_0.ident := identification_file;
    FileWrite_0.pSrc := ADR(data); 
    FileWrite_0.len := LEN(data); 
    FileWrite_0.offset := offset;
    FileWrite_0();
    

    IF FileWrite_0.status = 0 THEN
        
            step :=40;
       
        END_IF



40: FileClose_0.enable := TRUE;
    FileClose_0.ident := identification_file;
    FileClose_0();

    IF FileClose_0.status =0 THEN
        IF save = FALSE THEN
            step :=50;
        ELSE
            step := 25;
        END_IF
    END_IF

50: DevUnlink_0.enable := TRUE;
    DevUnlink_0.handle := DevLink_0.handle;
    DevUnlink_0();

    IF DevUnlink_0.status =0 THEN
        stav:= 0;
    END_IF
```

Comment: You will have to either read file or get file size, or remember size in separate variable.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in a comment, you will need to set the offset in the FileWrite FUB correspondingly.

I do this usually with the FileInfo FUB Guid *6eaf42f0-4ce5-44b7-95cb-275ae1c2fac5* in the AS help. It will tell you if the file exists already and also which size it has.

If it exists, the next step would be FileOpen, otherwise FileCreate.

Recently I have created a small project on GitLab which is, among other things, also appending a line to a file: https://gitlab.com/kirni/bur_robotic_sample/blob/master/bur_robotic_sample/Logical/Libraries/TeachLib/Teach.c

The code is in C, but I am sure you get the idea.

```
case stTEACH_INFO:

            /*setup fub*/
            this->fbInfo.enable = 1;
            this->fbInfo.pDevice = (UDINT)inst->szDevice;
            this->fbInfo.pName = (UDINT)inst->szFile;
            this->fbInfo.pInfo = &this->Info;

            //call fub
            FileInfo(&this->fbInfo);

            //fub is done..
            if(this->fbInfo.status != ERR_FUB_BUSY)
            {
                //file exists -> open it and append code
                if(this->fbInfo.status == ERR_OK)
                {
                    //start writing to the end of the file
                    this->Offset = this->Info.size;

                    //open existing file
                    this->Step = stTEACH_OPEN;
                }
                //file does not exist -> create it and insert code
                else if(this->fbInfo.status == fiERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
                {
                    //start writing at the beginning of the file
                    this->Offset = this->Info.size;

                    //crete new file
                    this->Step = stTEACH_CREATE;
                }
                //error
                else
                {
                    //set error status and goto error state
                    inst->Status = this->fbInfo.status;
                    this->Step = stTEACH_ERROR;
                }

                //disable fub
                this->fbInfo.enable = 0;            
                FileInfo(&this->fbInfo);
            }

            break;

        case stTEACH_CREATE:

            /*setup fub*/
            this->fbCreate.enable = 1;
            this->fbCreate.pDevice = (UDINT)inst->szDevice;
            this->fbCreate.pFile = (UDINT)inst->szFile;

            //call fub
            FileCreate(&this->fbCreate);

            //fub is done..
            if(this->fbCreate.status != ERR_FUB_BUSY)
            {
                //success
                if(this->fbCreate.status == ERR_OK)
                {
                    this->Ident = this->fbCreate.ident;

                    //open existing file
                    this->Step = stTEACH_WRITE;
                }           
                //error
                else
                {
                    //set error status and goto error state
                    inst->Status = this->fbCreate.status;
                    this->Step = stTEACH_ERROR;
                }

                //disable fub
                this->fbCreate.enable = 0;          
                FileCreate(&this->fbCreate);
            }

            break;

        case stTEACH_OPEN:

            /*setup fub*/
            this->fbOpen.enable = 1;
            this->fbOpen.pDevice = (UDINT)inst->szDevice;
            this->fbOpen.pFile = (UDINT)inst->szFile;
            this->fbOpen.mode = fiREAD_WRITE;

            //call fub
            FileOpen(&this->fbOpen);

            //fub is done..
            if(this->fbOpen.status != ERR_FUB_BUSY)
            {
                //success
                if(this->fbOpen.status == ERR_OK)
                {
                    this->Ident = this->fbOpen.ident;

                    //open existing file
                    this->Step = stTEACH_WRITE;
                }           
                //error
                else
                {
                    //set error status and goto error state
                    inst->Status = this->fbOpen.status;
                    this->Step = stTEACH_ERROR;
                }

                //disable fub
                this->fbOpen.enable = 0;            
                FileOpen(&this->fbOpen);
            }
            break;

        case stTEACH_WRITE:

            /*setup fub*/
            this->fbWrite.enable = 1;
            this->fbWrite.ident = this->Ident;
            this->fbWrite.offset = this->Offset;
            this->fbWrite.pSrc = this->szLine;
            this->fbWrite.len = this->Lenght;

            //call fub
            FileWrite(&this->fbWrite);

            //fub is done..
            if(this->fbWrite.status != ERR_FUB_BUSY)
            {
                //success
                if(this->fbWrite.status == ERR_OK)
                {
                    this->Ident = this->fbWrite.ident;

                    //Write existing file
                    this->Step = stTEACH_CLOSE;
                }           
                    //error
                else
                {
                    //set error status and goto error state
                    inst->Status = this->fbWrite.status;
                    this->Step = stTEACH_ERROR;
                }

                //disable fub
                this->fbWrite.enable = 0;           
                FileWrite(&this->fbWrite);
            }
            break;
```

However this should also work with the *filelen* output of the FileOpen FUB - just the way you did it. I would suggest, that you set a brakepoint just before writing and check if the offset is set on the FUB properly.

I would also recommend, that you call each FUB after it was done, again with *enable:=0* (like I did in my sample) i.e. disabling it. Some FUBs only update their inputs parameters on a positive edge on the *enable, execute, start,* etc. input command.

I hope this helps!